# General question regarding stable laws and domains of attraction

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I have a very general question: To what topic in probability theory do stable laws and domains of attractions belong to?

I found a chapter on "Stability and domains of attraction" in the book Regular Variation of Bingham et. al. So, it seems that these topics concern extreme value theory and fluctuation theory? Am I right to assume so?

Comment: I think I have read about this in Kolmogorov book: Limit Distributions for Sums of Independent Random Variables. It was somewhere in the middle of the book with precise definition.

Comment: I am not sure about the first one but I am positive about fluctuation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Much appreciated.